# plot sensor boolean data matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have data from two sensors that I want to visualize. Both sensors take  only 0/1 values. How can I change the xaxis labels to show the time series and y axis should have 2 labels 0 and 1 representing the value of sensors along the time series.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def drawgraph(inputFile):
    df=pd.read_csv(inputFile)
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    y = df[['sensor1']]
    x=df.index
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: If your data is set up correctly, pandas will automatically plot x axis with datetime. Try `df.plot(x='datetime', y='data')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have explained what you tried before asking a question for this to be meaningful. Anyway, below is the example.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

trange = pd.date_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="30min")
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':trange,'sensor1':np.round(np.random.rand(len(trange))),\
                   'sensor2':np.round(np.random.rand(len(trange)))})
df = df.set_index('time')
df.plot(yticks=[0,1],ylim=[-0.1,1.1],style={'sensor1':'ro','sensor2':'bx'})
```

[image]